# Cannot reconnect to mapped drives

Tags: windows-7, networking, security

Under Windows 7, I have mapped 4 drives, all of them pointing to my Synology 213j.

Everything works fine, but when I restart, the system complaints that it cannot reconnect to mapped drives and I have to enter again my credentials, which is a bit annoying.

I have configured the authentication level of "Send LM & NTLM" to use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated, under local policy Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Network security: LAN Manager authentication level, but that didn't seem to address the issue.

Any idea what else I may need to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem apparently was due to the credentials being under Generic Credentials instead of Windows Credentials in the Credential Manager.

Fixing this, solved the problem and now the drives reconnect on reboot.